# What is the size of my CUDA texture memory?

Tags: memory, cuda

How to interpret texture memory information output by `deviceQuery` sample to know texture memory size?
Here is output of my texture memory.

> Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)       1D=(65536), 2D=(65536,65535),3D=(2048,2048,2048)
>   Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers  1D=(16384) x 2048, 2D=(16384,16384) x 2048

Answer (score 9):

It is a common misconception, but there is no such thing as "texture memory" in CUDA GPUs. There are only textures, which are global memory allocations accessed through dedicated hardware which has inbuilt cache, filtering and addressing limitations which lead to the size limits you see reported in the documentation and device query. So the limit is either *roughly* the free amount of global memory (allowing for padding and alignment in CUDA arrays) or the dimensional limits you already quoted.

Comment: I've a big array allocated via cudaMalloc. This array need to be referred many times. I wanted to use feature of texture memory here. Is it possible?

Comment: @username_4567: You can bind linear memory allocated with `cudaMalloc` to a one dimensional texture. If you want higher dimensional textures you need to use pitched linear memory or a cuda array.

Comment: @talonmies
by pitched linear memory do you mean the memory allocated by cudaMalocPitch() ?

Comment: @sgar91: yes, `cudaMallocPitch` or `cudaMalloc3D` are the normal ways of allocating pitched linear memory.

Answer (score 3):

The output shows that the maximum texture dimensions are:

For 1D textures 65536
For 2D textures 65536*65535
For 3D textures 2048*2048*2048

If you want the size in bytes, multiply that by the maximum number of channels (4) and the maximum sub-pixel size (4B).

(For layered textures, multiply the relevant numbers you got for the dimensions by the number of maximum layers you got.)

However, this is the maximum size for a single texture, not the available memory for all textures.

Comment: But suppose I've chunk of data so how should I know whether that can accommodate in texture memory or not?

Comment: For that you need to query free memory (cuMemGetInfo), not maximum supported.